# How React renders elements?

Tags: reactjs

I think my question is simple and maybe you can find it useless, but i am new to react so i am sorry for that. However if i have a json file with translation, example main.json in DE folder with a link to an image and another in EN folder that has the same keys and link to the same image. When i change the language from DE to EN does react render again the image or not? Key and value are the same.

First main.json in DE

```
{
  "image":"linkToImage"
}
```

Second main.json in EN

```
{
  "image":"linkToImage"
}
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by `When i change the language from DE to EN` - what do you do, in the code, when that happens?

Comment: The rendering cycle of React is quite involved under the hood and depends on a few things from a development standpoint. We'll need more context/info about your specific use case to give you the answer you're looking for

Comment: Ok  i'am using i18next to translate my app. So if i want to iterate an array of images with descriptions i need to send to i18next.t()  the item to iterate and to translate too. So if you change language it will change the translation and for Music we have Musik, but the image link is always the same, so does react render it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one, and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the desired state. Even though we create an element describing the whole UI tree on every tick, only the text node whose contents have changed gets updated by React DOM.

Resources: https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html